# No such Element Found Issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the Xpath of the below element -

```
<ion-button class="ta-btn btn-red ios button button-block button-round button-outline ion-activatable ion-focusable hydrated"expand="block"fill="outline"mode="ios"shape="round"tabindex="1"type="submit"ng-reflect-expand="block"ng-reflect-fill="outline"ng-reflect-mode="ios"ng-reflect-shape="round"ng-reflect-type="submit">Sign In</ion-button>
```

It's not working due to the use of iframe and the whole code is written within the  below script:-

```html
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NDWL4GS"
  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
```

Comment: Before finding element, have you switched the focus to `iframe`?

Answer (score 0):

First `Switch` to `iframe` like below

```
String frame= driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));

driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

***OR***

```
Int size = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size();

driver.switchTo().frame(0); // index number `0` if you need to switch on first frame
```

*then* the `xpath` of the `element` would be like

```
//*[normailize-space()='Sign In']
```

***OR***

```
//*[contains(text(),'Sign In')]
```